# CGContextSaveGState performance

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am working on a app with image editing utilities where  i use CoreGraphics,in few scenarios  the images are huge  which is fetched from the server.Does **CGContextSaveGState** using often  has impact on the performance.

Comment: Measure it and find out using the Time Profiler instrument.

Comment: Thank You Rob mayoff for your suggestion.It helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

While rob mayoff's advice is very good and you should listen to him, I can spoil *part* of the reveal in this one case.

Yes. Saving and restoring gstates is very expensive. It's almost always cheaper to simply undo what you did.

That said, it's also usually much more readable code, so **you should still measure it to see whether or not it's *too* expensive in your case.** You might find that it's cheap enough that it's not worth the expense of rewriting the code to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you peter, i experimented using profiler for various scenarios as said by rob mayoff and decided when to use CGConextSaceState and when not to.